# Call Public void

Tags: android, class, void

I have a public void in one class and I want to call it in another class when it creates but nothing seems to be working. here is the code of my first activity

```
public class activityone extends Activity {

public void actionC() {

//actions

}
```

Does anyone know how to call it in my second class?

Comment: Please update your sample code to include your second class so we can understand what you're trying to do!

Comment: What im trying to do is to call that void(actionC) into my second class my. second class has nothing

Comment: The best way of doing this would be to make actionC() a static function (i.e., public static void actionC() {} ). This way, you can call it using activityone.actionC() you need not an instace of activityone.

Comment: @TusharDhoot, you can't possibly say if static invocation is the "best way" from this minimal example - perhaps activityone _needs_ to be instantiated. Until you know the purpose of the code, it's all pure supposition.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to have an instance of your activityone class in order to call an instance method.

To create an instance, you generally use a constructor like:

```
activityone a = new activityone();
a.actionC();
```

I'm not sure this is what you want though, because `Activity`s are generally created by the Android system itself and you should handle the `onCreate` method instead.

Comment: @SUPLMMM it's not crashing because of the code above - it's because of something you're doing inside your code. Do you have exception details?

Comment: What crashed?  It must be something in your constructor or actionC.  Creating a simple object and calling a simple function both work.  I was wondering if it had to do with extending `Activity` but I tested this and it worked with a void function that only did logging.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
public class activityone extends Activity {

/*public void actionC() {*/ //Instead on normal method, write your actions in onCreate()

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//actions
}
```

---

and in your second activity, do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),activityone.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps !!!